# How do you set a System property in the Oracle 10g JVM without using System.setProperty() directly?

Tags: java, oracle10g

How do you set a System property in the Oracle 10g JVM without using System.setProperty() directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you're referring to the JVM within an Oracle 10g database. If that is the case, then (inferring from the [Oracle 10g database documentation for DBMS_JAVA](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/appendixa.htm#BGBIGACA) here), it is not possible to set the properties for a Java session from an RDBMS session. The only choice therefore is to pass in values to the Java session and then invoke System.setProperty().

On the otherhand, it appears to be possible in the 11g database, if one goes by the [11g documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/java.112/e10588/chfour.htm#BABIIBIJ):

> ### Setting System Properties
>
> Within an RDBMS session you can
>   maintain a set of values that are
>   added to the system properties
>   whenever a Java session is started in
>   the RDBMS session. This set of values
>   remains valid for the duration of the
>   longer tier of Java session state,
>   which is typically the same as the
>   duration the RDBMS session.
>
> There is a set of PL/SQL functions in
>   the DBMS_JAVA package for setting,
>   retrieving, removing and displaying
>   key value pairs in an internal, RDBMS
>   session duration table, where both
>   elements of a pair are strings
>   (VARCHAR2) and there is at most one
>   pair for a given key. These functions
>   are as follows:
>
> - set_property
> - get_property
> - remove_property
> - show_property

Answer (score 2):

On the command line you can set -Dproperty=value

Or you can use System.getProperties().setProperty() or System.getProperties().put()/putAll()

Why would you want to set properties indirectly? Can you give an example?